# What do square brackets around one or multiple accent marks mean?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

Here's the phrase in question:
[image: sheet music fragment]
It comes from Dvořák's Slavonic Dances op. 46, no. 7, in a piano duet arrangement. I do not know the arranger; the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqlnupv0d-o) was not clear about that, but I think it is actually the version made by Dvořák himself.

I think that, because the line is repeated, the bracketed markings perhaps only have to be used the second time? Or the first? It is hard to hear in the recording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical use of square brackets is, to indicate an addition made by the editor, but not present in the original (*urtext*, in that case of the piano duet; this  is actually by Dvořák and preceded the orchestral version (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavonic_Dances)). Its first printing can be found at [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Slavonic_Dances%2C_Op.46_(Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k%2C_Anton%C3%ADn))).

Your proposed meaning is in my experience only expressible as text (e.g. "2nd time only"), and does not seem very likely in your example.

Comment: Okay, this is rather strange. So if the piano arrangement was made by the composer himself (and actually predates the orchestral version), then that means a later editor thought that he was better at composing than Dvořák and added these marks (which I see aren't present in the original piano duet)? I'm glad there's brackets then :)

Comment: @KeizerHarm: Some composers were pretty inconsistent with their notation. For example, sometimes they assumed if they wrote an articulation once over a figure, it would be played with that articulation if that musical figure occurs again. The earlier the piece of music, the more performers were assumed to *interpret* the score and read things that may have been abbreviated, not consistently shown, or sometimes just implicit stylistic conventions. I haven't looked at this particular piece, but there are often lots of good reasons that editors add things. (Editors can also be overzealous too.)